# Ionic 2 OneSignal IOS

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic3, api

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido em IONIC 2 e gerei a versão para IOS mas estou com problema com OneSignal. Já tentei reinstalar o plugin pelo ionic mas problema ainda continua.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente instalar o [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) e em seguida remover e adicionar novamente o plugin do `onesignal`. O CocoaPods facilita a implementação de libs no xcode.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
```

Se mesmo após o procedimento acima o erro continuar, tente abrir o arquivo `.xcworkspace` em vez do `.xcodeproj`